# Nordic countries, Sweden and Norway, similar top buildings colors

Tags: factoids, architecture, history, nordic-countries

I noticed this time I went to Stockholm, many of the traditional buildings has this green-sea color at the top of their roofs. For example, this is a common color in the towers of the buildings.

I am seeing also that buildings in Norway are painted with the same color, like the Trondheim cathedral.

Is there any historical reason for this? Any reference about this architecture feature?

Comment: Probably copper. You'll see this in Vancouver too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It comes down to a couple of reasons, for convenience and well, other:

Copper is often used in roofing, [both being an economical long term solution and looking good](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper_in_architecture#Roofing).  It's also very malleable and easily shaped for domes and curves.

> When properly designed and installed, a copper roof provides an
>   economical, long-term roofing solution. Tests on European copper roofs
>   from the 18th century showed that, in theory, copper roofs can last
>   one thousand years

Then why green? From the introduction of that article:

> Copper’s most famous trait is its display from a bright metallic
>   colour to iridescent brown to near black an**d finally to a greenish
>   verdigris patina**. Architects describe the array of browns as russet,
>   chocolate, plum, mahogany, and ebony. **The metal’s distinctive
>   green patina has long been coveted by architects and designers.**

This suggests that it's a building convenience, cost-saving, and trendy measure, copied and shared between architects and builders throughout Europe.

One final coincidence is that [2 Kings 19:26 mentions 'the grass on the housetops'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_roof#Israel), and perhaps it's a pleasant coincidence to have a green-topped building.

Comment: Great answer. [This (Norwegian) newspaper article](http://www.dagbladet.no/2010/07/19/nyheter/nidarosdomen/olavsfestdagene/12627207/) explains how they got the roof green after doing some restoration. Directly translated: "We have used urine from cows and horses which we smeared on the copper, and thus we get the green color in a relatively short time [...]"

Comment: @JoeBlow these weren't exactly built in the modern economy...they're old.

Comment: yes, but it's just a silly comment on wikipedia.  it's almost impossible to CU now with the cost. you have to just go with lead. ("just") the price exploded a few yrs back.  Robert's linked article is about modern use of copper

Comment: Could also add that Sweden had several copper mines, and from the copper they made enormous "coins" , which actually were suited to be used as roofing-tiles as they were.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_copper_currency_in_Sweden

Comment: Note that using heavy metals like copper and lead in roofs can pollute the ground and surface water if used on a large scale. Heavy metals are quite toxic.

Comment: @RHA Lead is *far* more toxic to humans than copper.

Comment: @jpatokal true. But both are more toxic than normal stone roofs